# Get generic field value from list of generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a bunch of settings that can be one of many types. For example, URL, text, number, etc. Based on other posts I came up with the following that seems to work okay:

```
public abstract class SettingViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SettingType Type { get; set; }

    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public Module? Module { get; set; }
}

public class SettingViewModel<T> : SettingViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

My biggest problem with this is that when it comes time to read the values in Value for each setting I want to do have a method like. I wouldn't want to change the shape of this method really, because I want to keep it generic and it will be exposed as a Controller Method in MVC

```
    public void Update(SettingViewModel Setting)
    {
        GS_SysConfig setting = new GS_SysConfig();

        //might also just use a util function to convert to string based on the type of Value
        setting.ConfigVal = Setting.Value.ToString(; //Value is not a field in the abstract class
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This won't work because Value is not a field in the parent class, and I suppose I could come up with some way of doing casting and and getting types and such, but it seems messy and not very elegant. Is there a better approach to tryign to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Update:
ConfigVal is of type String

Comment: You may want to consider using `dynamic`, specifically on the `Setting` parameter (nitpick, should be `setting`).

Comment: what would be the case against using dynamic?

Comment: `public void Update<T>(SettingViewModel<T> Setting)`

Comment: What is the type of `setting.ConfigVal`?

Comment: @TruthOf42 You move from compile-time validation to run-time validation namely; you could easily have a `SettingViewModel<int>` passed in and trying to assign to a property of type `string`, which would throw at runtime instead of being caught at compile time.